# Removing duplicate page elements - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to get a list of elements with a certain tag and if there is more than one loop through and remove the additional elements.

Currently I do:

```
if (document.getElementsByName("description")[0]) {
  document.getElementsByName("description")[0].setAttribute("content", "My Description");
} else {
  var meta = document.createElement('meta');
  meta.name = "description";
  meta.content = "My Description";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
}
```

But I want to remove anything that is after the first element? How would I do that?

Comment: Is you problem the loop or is it about how to remove the elements? What did you try to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
[...document.getElementsByTagName('span')].slice(1).forEach(e=>e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
[...document.getElementsByTagName('div')].slice(1).forEach(e=>e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
```

First select all elements with the specific tag name. Transform it to an array (in this case with spread operator, you can also use `[].slice.call(...)`. After that you can call slice on that array of elements and remove the first one out of this set. Loop through the elements and remove them. That's all :)

**EDIT** Solution for beginners:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for(var i=elements.length-1;i>0;i--)
  elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
```

Comment: You solution for beginners won't work, `getElementsByTagName` returns a live HTMLCollection, so as soon as an element is removed from the DOM it will also be removed from `elements`, so you will skip multiple elements if you do it that way.

Comment: You're so right @t.niese. My bad. I fixed it. Now it works as expected. I remembered this problem too late and forgot to fix it. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

If you want cut anything after description[0] in header, you can use that
    'document.getElementsByTagName["head"].innerHTML = "";'

If you only want cut any description tags, use

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('description');
for(i=0; i<tags.length; i++){
  tags[i].remove();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever try your suggestion? First of all, this won't run because `document.getElementsByTag['description']` would throw an `cannot read property description of undefined`. If you would  change it to `document.getElementsByTagName('description')` then it would still not work, because it the `for .. in` would iterate over `length`. And `getElementsByTagName` returns a live HTMLCollection, so you would skip elements, and you would access keys that don't exists anymore.

Comment: Yes its true, I did not pay attention to what I was writing, I correct it immediately although the solution was found.